# Why we are using (*) operator to declare functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dereference

I have noticed in many cases people are using "*" operator when declaring functions in a class or in outside. 
ex -

```
T* sortArray(T data[], int arrsize);
Savings * newSavings(int NaccntNo);
```

So i would like to know why are we using this "*" operator middle of function declaration and what is the pros and cons of it.

Comment: That is not the de-reference operator. It is not a multiplication either. Unfortunately, C++ re-uses symbols for different things.

Comment: okay let me edit thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1):

```
T* sortArray(T data[], int arrsize);
Savings * newSavings(int NaccntNo);
```

`T*` or `Savings *` indicates, this function returns address, in first case address of type `T` (generic) and in second case address of type `Savings`

Comment: Return address to what?

Comment: @Optimuskck From wherever it is getting called. Say, `Savings * ptr= newSavings(10);` Here, it is returned to ptr.